# Service crashes on app close

Tags: java, android

I am building an app to remind me stuff. I am using alarm manager for repeated alarms. ***But the problem when i set multiple alarms, if i close the app the first alarm service crashes, the second one works fine. I don't know why.***

```
public void setReminder(){
        Calendar dm = Calendar.getInstance();
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity , broadcast.class);
        intent.putExtra("com.todolist.dailylist.data" , listUID);
        PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),alarmID, intent , PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        int month = Integer.parseInt(splitDate(date)[1]);
        dm.set(Calendar.MONTH, month -1 );
        dm.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(splitDate(date)[0]));
        dm.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(splitDate(date)[2]));
        dm.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.parseInt(formatTime(timeVar)[0]));
        dm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(formatTime(timeVar)[1]));

        if(formatTime(timeVar)[2].equals("AM")) {
            dm.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
        }else if(formatTime(timeVar)[2].equals("PM")){
            dm.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
        }

        long when = dm.getTimeInMillis();
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,when, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY  ,pendingintent);
    }
```

Broadcast receiver code

```
public class broadcast extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String intentID = intent.getStringExtra("com.todolist.dailylist.data");
        Intent service = new Intent(context, service.class);
        service.putExtra("com.todolist.dailylist.listID", intentID);
        context.startService(service);
    }
}
```

Service shows a overlay window when the alarm triggers like the most to do apps.

Service class .

```
public class service extends Service {
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private View myview;
    private diUtil databaseutil;
    private String listID;
    private String value = null;
    private TextView listTitle;
    private TextView listDescription;
    private RelativeLayout rootLayout;
    private RelativeLayout controllerIcons;
    private ImageButton doneImage;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        databaseutil = new diUtil(this);
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER;

        myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notificationwindow , null);

        listTitle = (TextView)myview.findViewById(R.id.listTitleHeader);
        listDescription = (TextView)myview.findViewById(R.id.listDescriptionHeader);
        controllerIcons = (RelativeLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.controller_icons);
        rootLayout = (RelativeLayout)myview.findViewById(R.id.layout_controller);
        doneImage = (ImageButton) myview.findViewById(R.id.doneIconController);
        windowManager.addView(myview, params);


    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        listID = intent.getStringExtra("com.todolist.dailylist.listID");
        ArrayList<listData> data = databaseutil.getListitem(listID);
        for(int i=0; i < data.size();i++){
            listTitle.setText(data.get(i).getListName());
            if(data.get(i).getListText() != null){
                Toast.makeText(this, "description present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else if(data.get(i).getListText() == null){
                Toast.makeText(this, "description not present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            doneImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    windowManager.removeView(myview);

                }
            });

        }

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }





    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        windowManager.removeView(myview);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Here's the error i got from the logcat console

```
 Process: com.todolist.dailylist, PID: 5601
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.todolist.dailylist.services.service@6a10f79 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3314)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1565)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                     at com.todolist.dailylist.services.service.onStartCommand(service.java:74)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3297)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1565) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Anybody knows why this happens and how to solve this issue ?. Thank you so much for reading. Highly appreciated !.

Comment: Hint: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`. Problem cause by the `intent` are null when you call `.getStringExtra`. Let's debug to check it

Comment: But's it null one first time, if there's a second alarm second alarm works fine without that error. i don't understand why

Comment: You may google for problem about: null Intent + onStartCommand. Because of problem came from `onStartCommand` method. I don't really good on android so I just can help you with a suggest solution